# How to structure correctly route and folders in emberjs?

Tags: ember.js

Say I have this folder structure:

```
- app
-- pods
--- dashboard
----- zones
------ index
------- controller.js
------- route.js
------- template.hbs
------ show
------- areas
-------- controller.js
-------- route.js
-------- template.hbs
------- controller.js
------- route.js
------- template.hbs
```

And in `router.js`

```
    this.route('zones', function() {
      this.route('show', { path: ':zone_id/cities' }, function() {
        this.route('areas', { path: ':city_id/areas'});
      });
    });
```

Now

When I visit 
`dashboard/zones` - all zones will be loaded

And when I clicked one item from zones, it will be redirected to
`dashboard/zones/1/cities` which will load cities in page

And when I clicked one item from cities, it will be redirected to
`/dashboard/zones/1/cities/4/areas` -

Now the problem is `/dashboard/zones/1/cities/4/areas` url is correctly hit, but the template is not showing.

What is missing or wrong with my setup ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `{{outlet}}` in the parent template.